# When using automatic proxy configuration in IE, does the settings get stored locally?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, proxy

If I'm on a corporate computer which has automatically configured proxy settings, can I still find out the proxy settings locally? Like for instance checking the following registry key?

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]`

With *automatic settings* I mean either by script or "autodetect":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a sort-of-answer, I'm afraid, but in the case where you've specified a script it should be possible to just fetch the script from the same location (in the general case, if I recall correctly, it's served over http) and extract the settings from that.

Obviously that doesn't help with the "autodetect" option.